# HorizontalPager not recomposing everytime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

i am using a HorizontalPager and im passing values to it, and one of the tabs receiving a boolean is not very consistent, sometimes the value passes and some othertimes it is not passing to the tab composable and i can't update my screen , here's an example :

```
 HorizontalPager(
    pageCount = tabSize,
    state = pagerState,
    userScrollEnabled = true,
) { page ->
     when (page) {
        0 -> Screen(
            state1= privateState,
        )

        1 -> Screen2(
            onEvent= {},
        )

        2 -> Screen3(

            onEvent2= {},
        )

        3 -> Screen4(
            
            isUpdate= isValue // i have this boolean value not always updating correctly even though the value is changing and i can see it changing in the log but not in the Screen4
        )

    }
}
```

is there anything to force pager tabs recomposed with every changing property ?

Comment: i noticed that if i negate the isvalue ,it will always work fine, 
like isUpdate = !isValue

Comment: What is `isValue`? How is it declared, where you get it from, how are you changing it?

Comment: from another composable,and it is a stateflow collectedasStateWithLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

turns out that i need to use

```
val isRead by remember(isValue){
       mutableStateOf(isValue)
      }
```

and i then pass

```
isUpdate = isRead
```

that way it is recomposing correctly and on every update , initially tried that and did not ork because my isRead was inside the pager composable, it need to be outside

Comment: This won't be needed if you treat your StateFlow correctly. Your problem is most likely somewhere else and this just hides it, but does not solve it. If you post your whole code, I can help you find it.